# How to set custom font for label in custom tableviewcelll?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I wish to set custom `font` and `color` for a label in custom tableviewcell.
I tried writing the code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` , `willDisplayCell` and in `custom cell` class but they are not working.

Could anyone tell exactly where to write the code for the same .

Thanks

Comment: Show some code what have you tried?

Comment: clubCellObj.clubAddress.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Champagne&Limousines" size:9];

clubCellObj.clubAddress.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.545 green:0.773 blue:0.247 alpha:1.0];

objClubCell is an object of custom table view cell

Comment: did you got textcolor? It seems to be good..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  - (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
     if (cell == nil)
     {
          cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     }
     UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
     [label setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
}
```

Dont forget to set your label tag in the prototype cell to 100 and set your cell identifier as "cell"

Comment: @sreejith.virgo But you talk about custom tableview cell. How is it working for you? It's correct code for normal tableview cell.

Comment: @Mani.. i think he just got confused about prototype cells and custom tableview cell

Comment: @AravindNair: I tagged label in custom tableviewcell and used object name of custom tableviewcell class instead of "cell".
It worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using standard cell. In cellFoRowAtIndexpath: you can do something like this:

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"some_font_name"  size:cell.textLabel.font.pointSize];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor] //this will set color to red
```

Comment: I'm using a custom cell with name "objClubCell" and a label in it named "clubAddress"

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to set the custom fonts in your project than first you have to add the .otf or .ttf file in your project. and also you need to add it to your Info.plist file like this...

[image]

and If you wish to set it for your customcell than you can do it in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
using....

```
[cell.lblData setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Regular" size:28.0]];
```

Comment: Thanks, But I have already used the same fonts for other labels in project after doing what you have mentioned.

Comment: than what's the problem?

Comment: The issue was while when doing the same for a label inside a custom table view cell.

Comment: Both work the same way buddy. and make sure you are setting your lbl.text after setFont

Comment: yes, I thought the same but It did work.
Anyway thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

oky, lets try this way,

in your `custom cell.h` file

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

  @interface CustomCelll : UITableViewCell
  @property(nonatomic, retain)UILabel *label; //add a property 

  @end
```

in `customCell.m` file

```
 #import "CustomCelll.h"
 @implementation CustomCelll
 @synthesize label;//label

 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
 {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
     if (self) {

     UILabel *lab = [[UILabel alloc]init];//init it,
     self.label = lab;
     //now hear only set all the property 
     self.label.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];//set the color 
     self.label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy-Bold" size:13];//set the font
     [self addSubview:self.label];
     [lab release];//under the non ARC

  }
     return self;
}


 - (void)layoutSubviews
   {
      [super layoutSubviews];
      //set frame for ur label
      self.label.frame = CGRectMake(20, 3, 100, 30);

   }
```

now in controller

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
       CustomCell *aCell = [self.aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
       if(aCell == nil)
        {
            aCell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        }
        aCell.label.text = @"Hello"; //just set the text 
        return aCell;
   }
```

hope this helps u :)